# regular expression for java

Tags: java, expression

I am trying to write regular expression . The requirements are: the expression should be written in cyrilic alphabet also it can contains any numbers and any symbols like !@#$%^&*() and so on only latin letters are excluded. My problem is that  my expression doesn't include all these paticular symbols like !@#$... my expression is ^[а-яА-ЯёЁa0-9]+$. I do Test :

```
@Test
public void matchAnEmptyStringOrASpecificOtherPattern() {

    String input = "";
    // ^[а-яА-ЯёЁa0-9]+$
    assertTrue( Pattern.compile("^[а-яА-ЯёЁa0-9]+$").matcher(input).find()    

);
```

How to include these symbols in my pattern .

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z]` matches everything except latin letters A through Z. Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ranges with cyrillic characters (e.g. `[а-я]`).

If you want to match only cyrillic characters, numbers and characters in the `!@#$` set, what you probably want is this:

```
assertTrue(
    Pattern.compile(
      // | cyrillic and supplementary blocks
      // |                                            | the rest
        "(\\p{InCyrillic}|\\p{InCyrillic_Supplementary}|[!@#$0-9])+"
    )
    .matcher(input)
    // match all input (instead of "find" with "^" and "$")
    .matches()
);
```

**Example**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(\\p{InCyrillic}|\\p{InCyrillic_Supplementary}|[!@#$0-9])+"
);

System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$1").matches()); // true
System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$abc").matches()); // false, has western letters
```

Comment: No the first one is not true

Comment: System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$1").matches()); // true

Comment: it is false  . not true

Comment: `System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$1").matches()); ` will return `true`. As intended. You have cyrillic characters, characters in the `!@#$` range, and a digit.

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "(\\p{InCyrillic}|\\p{InCyrillic_Supplementary}|[!@#$0-9])+"
        );

        System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$1").matches()); // true
        System.out.println(p.matcher("я!Я@#$abc").matches()); // false, has western letters

Comment: it shows fals false in both cases . I copy your example

Comment: What JRE/version are you using? I've tested this with Oracle Java and it does return as intended. Try self-containing this in a test application.

Comment: which version do u have ?

Comment: Oracle JRE8 too. Are you testing this literally? The only thing I can think of is that some hidden whitespace is in there somewhere in your test string...